# Converting NSNumber to NSString is not realy a string

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber

I have got a problem with converting an `NSNumber` value to an `NSString`

MyPowerOnOrNot is an `NSNumber` witch can only return a 1 or 0
and `myString` is an `NSString`..

```
myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [myPowerOnOrNot stringValue]];

NSLog(@"%@",myString);
if(myString == @"1") {
    [tablearrayPOWERSTATUS addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"ON"]];
}
else if(myString == @"0") {
    [tablearrayPOWERSTATUS addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"OFF"]];
}
```

What is wrong with this?

The `NSLog` shows 0 or 1 in the console as a string but I can't check it if it is 1 or 0 in an if statement?

If doesn't jump into the statements when it actually should.. I really don't understand why this doesn't works.. 
Any help would be very nice!

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: Why do you want to convert the NSNumber to a string? Why not compare it directly to integers rather than converting it to a string and comparing against strings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of problems

```
myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [myPowerOnOrNot stringValue]];
```

[-stringValue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000178-BABDCAEI) sent to an `NSNumber` gives you a reference to a string.  The format specifier `%d` is for the C `int` type.  What would happen in this case is that myString would contain the address of the NSString returned by `[myPowerOnOrNot stringValue]`.  Or, on 64 bit, it would return half of that address.  You could actually use `[myPowerOnOrNot stringValue]` directly and avoid the relatively expensive `-stringWithFormat:`

```
if(myString == @"1")
```

`myString` and `@"1"` are not necessarily the same object.  Your condition only checks that the references are identical.  In general with Objective-C you should use `-isEqual:` for equality of objects, but as we know these are strings, you can use `-isEqualToString:`

```
if ([[myPowerOnOrNot stringValue] isEqualToString: @"1"])
```

Or even better, do a numeric comparison of your NSNumber converted to an int.

```
if ([myPowerOnOrNot intValue] == 1)
```

Finally if `myPowerOnOrNot` is not supposed to have any value other than 0 or 1, consider having a catchall `else` that asserts or throws an exception just in case `myPowerOnOrNot` accidentally gets set wrong by a bug.

Answer (score 1):

"myString " is a reference to a string, not the value of the string itself.

The == operator will compare the reference to your string literal and so never return true.

Instead use

```
 if( [myString isEqualToString:@"1"] )
```

This will compare the value of myString to "1"

Comment: thank you very much , it works now! and i have learned something again =)

Comment: While this is *technically* true; for this particular case there are a few other problems that should be addressed; among other things `myPowerOnOrNot` being turned into a string in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

In Objective C; you can't compare strings for equality using the `==` operator.

What you want to do here is as follows:

```
[tablearrayPOWERSTATUS addObject:([myPowerOnOrNot integerValue]?@"ON":@"OFF"])];
```

Compact, fast, delicious.

Comment: That is actually not a direct replacement for the code in the question.

Comment: @JeremyP: Actually, it is. As far as I can see, the code in the question is already free from error correction; so I'm assuming that the assumption of the number always coming in as 1 or 0 holds. `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"string"]` is pointless, as it works out to `@"string"`; and the code in the question gives no internal reason that myString needs to exist.

Comment: The first line of his code pretty much guarantees that the string his is comparing is neither 0 or 1 since he is converting a pointer to a string using the %d format specifier.  Your code would add `@"ON"` or `@"OFF"` to the array.  His code, even with the comparisons fixed would add nothing to the array.

Comment: and your code adds @"ON" if myPowerOnOrOff contains an invalid number, his ignores such values.

Comment: @JeremyP: His initial conversion is *obviously* a bug.